# Tell a macro to check if object exists and if yes do A. but if no then do B.?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I use MS Excel 2007.

I have the following code in a macro that creates two Option Buttons (not active X) into Cell `B25`.

```
Range("B25").Select
ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(129.75, 540, 24, 20.25).Select
Selection.Name = " Select1Button "

Range("B25").Select
ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(225.75, 540, 79.5, 21.75).Select
Selection.Name = " Select2Button "
```

Is there a way for the macro to check if either already exists in Cell 'B25' and if they do then do nothing and finish the rest of the Macro but if they do not then create them as described above?

Something like:

```
In CellB25 does "Select1Button" & "Select2Button" Exist?
Yes = Then ignore the ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add code and continue to run 
the rest of the macro code.

No - Then run the ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add code and continue to run the 
rest of the macro code.
```

I have been stuck on this for hours!

Comment: Let me say that Option button can be created in cell as well as ActiveX controls also. And you can set further action accordingly. Check my post will help you lot ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to suggest you the solution in two parts.**

***Part one*** will help you to create `Option Button` in Cells.

*And **Part two** will help you to determine that which `Option Button` has been clicked, to execute further actions.*

**Part 1:**

*This VBA (Macro) will help you to create `Two Option buttons` in Cell `C1` & `D1` with Group/Frame.*

```
Sub AddOptionButtons()
    Dim btn1 As OptionButton
    Dim btn2 As OptionButton
    Dim btn3 As OptionButton
    Dim grbox As GroupBox
    Dim t As Range
    Dim s As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Delete
    ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Delete

    For i = 1 To 1 Step 1
        Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3))
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 4))

        Set btn1 = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        Set btn2 = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(s.Left, s.Top, s.Width, s.Height)
        Set grbox = ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width + 50, t.Height)

        With btn1
          .Caption = ""
          .Display3DShading = True
          .LinkedCell = "E" & i
        End With

        With btn2
          .Caption = ""
          .Display3DShading = True
        End With

        With grbox
          .Caption = "My Group"
          .Visible = True
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Copy & Paste this code as Standard Module.
2. `For i = 1 To 1 Step 1` determines that `2 
   Option Buttons` will be created in `Row 1`.
3. If you need to create `4 Option Buttons` the 
   it should be, `For i = 1 To 2 Step 1`.
4. `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 3)` determines 
   that `i` is `Row value` and `3` is `Column`, 
   are editable.
5. `Lined Cell to Option Buttons` is `E1`, which 
    is editable.

**Part 2:**

*This Macro will help you to determine that which `Option Button` has been Clicked to take further action.*

```
Sub TheSelectCase()

  Select Case Range("E1").Value

  Case 1
   Your Code for further action.
  Case 2
   Your Code for further action.

  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help you @kenny keep asking☺

Answer (score 0):

Draft code:

```vb
public sub createoptionbutton(xname,a,b,c,d)
dim obj as object
xname=trim(xname)
for each obj in activesheet.optionbuttons
    if obj.name=xname then exit sub
next
activesheet.optionbuttons.add(a,b,c,d).select
selection.name=xname
end sub
```

Edit it as you need.

PS. You do not need to select any cell before optionbox creation - it doesn't matter. Simply point to a specific worksheet instead of ActiveSheet. And I'd recommend to set the GroupBox property additionally.

PPS. At the request of [Rajesh S](https://superuser.com/users/711214/rajesh-s) - the function which checks the optionbutton existence only:

```vb
public function optionbuttonexists(xname) as boolean
dim obj as object
xname=trim(xname)
for each obj in activesheet.optionbuttons
    if obj.name=xname then 
        optionbuttonexists = true
        exit sub
    end if
next
end function
```

... and backward function

```
public function optionbuttonabsent(xname) as boolean
dim obj as object
xname=trim(xname)
for each obj in activesheet.optionbuttons
    if obj.name=xname then exit sub
next
optionbuttonabsent=true
end function
```

The last function allows to solve author's task as

```
if optionbuttonabsent(" Select2Button ") then
    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(225.75, 540, 79.5, 21.75).Select
    Selection.Name = " Select2Button "
end if
```

Comment: Your code needs some correction,,, `public sub createoptionbutton(xname,a,b,c,d)` will never  work ,,, and OP demands how to check existence of an Option Buttons   !

Comment: @RajeshS *will never work* Of course, it must be called. But one who creates the code posted in question can do it I think... *OP demands how to check existence of an Option Buttons* The most part of the code does just that.